# Shall I install anaconda, with Python3 and R already installed?

Tags: python, r, anaconda

On my Ubuntu 18.04, I have Python 3 and R installed. I am about to study some data science and just found https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/.

anaconda comes with Python and R and some packages. Will installing anaconda conflict with my existing installation of Python 3 and R?

Shall I install anaconda, or shall I install the packages manually and individually on demand?

How do people in data science install the tools?

Comment: Short answer: you do not have to! Since it is already discussed and pretty much reflects all pros and cons, I prefer to point you out to this answer: https://www.quora.com/Why-should-I-use-anaconda-instead-of-traditional-Python-distributions-for-data-science.